# Am I wrong in understanding random variables in this way

Tags: probability, probability-theory, analysis

I am learning stochastic process and is confused about the definition of random variable.
Here is what I understand .
We know that the three basic elements of a probability space is $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$, and the probability function is defined in $\mathscr{F}$, but the random variable is defined in $\Omega$.
And I understand in this way, for example.
Suppose that the $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ and the $\mathscr{F}$ is $\{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4, 5 ,6\}, 
\Omega, \varnothing\}$. I can define the probability as $P(\{1, 2, 3\}) = P(\{4, 5 ,6\}) = 0.5$, but I can not define the random variable in $\Omega$, because there is no element in $\Omega$ that satisfies $\{\omega : X(w) \leq x \} \in \mathscr{F}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A random variable is a function $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ which is measurable with respect to the measures $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$. This is equivalent to $X$ verifying that for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $X((-\infty , x]) = \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\} \in \mathcal{F}$. Note that this definition does not involve your probability function $P$. If you find an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that no $\omega$ in $\Omega$ satisfies $X(\omega) \leq x$, then $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\} = \varnothing$. But $\varnothing \in \mathcal{F}$, so finding such an $x$ does not prove that $X$ fails to be a random variable over $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.

For an example of a random variable on the sigma algebra that you defined, consider $X$ such that $X(\omega)= 7$ if $\omega \in \{1,2,3\}$ and $X(\omega)= 15$ if $\omega \in \{4,5,6\}$. Then we have that:

$$\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\}=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\varnothing \quad \text{ if }(x) < 7 \\ 
\{1,2,3\} \quad \text{ if } 7 \leq x < 15 \\
\Omega \quad \text{ if }  x \geq 15 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

So the set $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x\}$ is measurable for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and thus $X$ is measurable.

Comment: So could you explain my example. Is it right that the only random variable I can define on $\Omega$ is $\varnothing$. I prefer things more practical

Comment: No, that's not right (besides, $\varnothing$ is not a function). I've added an example of a random variable in my answer.

Comment: The domain of my example is $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 \}$, and it sends $1, 2$ and $3$ to $7$ and $4,5$ and $6$ to $15$. Again, the empty set is not a random variable, it s a set. A random variable is a function $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, so it takes elements in $\Omega$ and sends them to points in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh okay. In that case, your example does not define a probability space. By definition of sigma algebra, the elements of $\mathcal{F}$ must be subsets of $\Omega$. But since the elements of $\Omega$ are sets of single elements, its subsets must be sets of sets. Since, for example, $\{1,2,3\}$ is a set and not a set of sets, then $\mathcal{F}$ is not well defined, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about measurable functions over $\Omega$.

Comment: By the way, note that, for the braces to show on your mathjax equation, you have to add a backslash before each brace. I've edited your post accordingly.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I totally understand you. One last question, we know that X is a measurable function, so it takes  ‘elements’ in $\Omega$, needs to satisfy $X^{-1}(\Omega) \in \mathscr{F}$, but how can an element $\in$ the set of sets? I mean if $\omega = 1$, it does not $\in $$\{\{1\}\}$

Comment: First off, the expression $X^{-1}(\Omega) $ doesn't make sense. The expression $X^{-1}(A)$ denotes $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in A\}$, so the $A$ in the expression must be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, which $\Omega$ isn't. As I told you, in your example, $\mathscr{F}$ does not define a sigma field over $\Omega$, so it doesn't make sense to talk about measurable functions. In particular, a set  $X^{-1}(A)$ will be a subset of $\Omega$ and thus a set of sets, which is not a set and therefore cannot be an element of $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: I have already fixed the mistake and $\Omega$ is just a typo. In your example, I know that $\omega$ is an element of$\Omega$, but it can only be a number of it. You said that X($\omega$) = 7 if $\omega \in \{1, 2, 3\}$, but the elements of $\mathcal{F} $ are all sets. How can a number belong to a set of sets.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Assuming you are taking $\Omega$ to be $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, then note that $X$ is defined over $\Omega$ and not $\mathcal{F}$, so in the expression $X(\omega)$, the $\omega$ is an element of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (i.e. a number from $1$ to $6$), and not an element of $\mathcal{F} = \{\{1, 2, 3\}, \{4, 5 ,6\},
\Omega, \varnothing\}$ (which would be a set). I encourage you to read carefully the definitions of probability space, sigma field and measurable function, as they can be quite confusing at first.

Comment: You are following and I am true a green hand, a random variable’s domain needs to be the intersection of $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}$? Because it is based on $\Omega$ and needs to have probability, i.g. $\{$\omega$ $\in$ $\Omega$, X($\omega$)<= x \}$ $\in$ \mathcal{F}$

Comment: The domain of $X$ is $\Omega$. Note that the intersection of $\Omega$ and $\mathcal{F}$ is generally $\varnothing$, since the former is a set and the latter is a set of sets, so the elements of the former are points and the elements of the latter are sets. Measurability of a function is a property similar to continuity: it's related to the behaviour of the function, and imposing restrictions to the domain is not necessary to make it a random variable.